# Using R to create a new database of duplicates

Tags: r, duplicates

In R -

I'm trying to create a new dataset which shows employees whose employee ID appears more than once on the original data.

I basically want the single appearances of employee IDs deleted

I've found solutions that give me a count on the number of IDs but not that gives me the full list.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but `table(df$employee_ID)` will give you the number of times each employee appears and you can then filter for those employee IDs in your original table to see all the rows with employees who appear multiple times. If that sounds right let me know and I'll write a full answer.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

library(dplyr)

your_data %>% group_by(employee_id) %>% mutate(freq=1:n()) %>% ungroup %>% filter(freq>1) -> duplicated_rows

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R solution:

```
freq <- table(df$employee_id)
```

That will create a frequency table with two columns, Var1 (employee ID) and Freq (number of times that employee ID appears in the dataframe).

We can then filter `freq` to just get a vector of IDs:

```
freqs <- freq[freq$Freq > 1,]$Var1
```

And then filter the original dataframe for those IDs, which should show all rows containing employees who appear multiple times.

```
df[df$employee_id %in% freqs,]
```

---

A slight variation is to directly filter from freq without the intermediate table:

```
df[df$employee_id %in% freq[freq$Freq > 1,]$Var1,]
```

---

Or, by grabbing the `left_join` function from `dplyr`, you can join the frequency table on to the original df and filter from there:

```
df <- dplyr::left_join(df, freq, by = c('employee_id' = 'Var1')
df <- df[df$Freq > 1,]
```

That could be useful if you want to later filter for employees with, say, 3 or 5 appearances because it keeps the frequency column with the dataframe.